# Regex: Match <img> tag if width or height is smaller than 100px

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

i would love to get rid of some tiny images in a rssfeed by matching and removing them with Apples NSRegularExpressions.

```
<img src="somepic" height="1" width="1"> should be matched for removal
<img src="somepic" height="50" width="100"> -> should also be matched
<img src="somepic" height="100" width="100"> -> this one should not be matched
```

my current approach is not working yet

```
<img(\s*[height|width]\s*=\s*"([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])"\s*+|[^>]+?)*>
```

my guess is there is some problem with the capture groups (which are probably not needed at all). Does anyone have a hint why its not working?

Comment: The problem is that *all* `img` attributes must match the first capture group, which fails for the `src` attribute. You need to make sure your check only applies to `width` and `height` attributes, but leave other attributes such as `src` alone. (Also, `[height|width]` should be something like `(height|width)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
<img[^>]*(?:height|width)\s*=\s*"[1-9]?[0-9]"[^>]*>
```

It fixes the small issues you had, that Mattias Buelens mentioned in his comment.

See on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/1HPUxNUQtV).

Comment: Thanks Morja. I added the handling for px and em in the height, width attributes. http://www.rubular.com/r/OYcuO8cwzr  <img[^>]*(?:height|width)\s*=\s*"[1-9]?[0-9](px)*(em)*"[^>]*>

Answer (score 1):

This is in `c#` regex

```
(?<=<img).*?(height="([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])".*?width="([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])"|width="([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])".*?height="([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])").*?(?=>)
```

Hope this helps..